# Record read access based on field value in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Entity has a custom field based on which, some security roles should have access to records of that type and some should not.

Javascript can be used to close form after checking roles. But I'm looking for back end solution that will disabled access to this records in workflows and searches too.

For example, product should viewable by everyone if manufacturer is our company and only by Competitor Products Specialist if other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing the plugin that works on pre-Retrieve event and modifies retrieve query by adding additinal filter by field.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to write a plugin that would automatically share the record with the appropriate Users/Teams. When somebody updates that field, the plugin would run and share/unshare the record according to your business logic.

Disclaimer: I haven't actually tried this before, and there may be performance issues if you have lots of records (and therefore lots of sharing records).

Comment: Problem is I needed restrictive mechanism not vise versa.